# Как из массива properties вывести параметр property?

Tags: php, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста вывести из массива параметр `property`.
Я обращаюсь к этому массиву, но получаю **Undefined index: property**.
Что я делаю не так?

```
'properties' => 
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'product_id' => '29',
    'property_id' => '13',
    'property' => 'Prevents cancer',
    'category' => 'Health benefits ',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'product_id' => '29',
    'property_id' => '15',
    'property' => 'Eye care',
    'category' => 'Health benefits ',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'product_id' => '29',
    'property_id' => '16',
    'property' => 'Weight Loss',
    'category' => 'Health benefits ',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'product_id' => '29',
    'property_id' => '12',
    'property' => 'Heart health',
    'category' => 'Health benefits ',
  ),
),
)
 <?php
      $properties = $product['property'];
       echo '<ul>';
       foreach ($properties as $property){
         $product['property'];
        }
       echo '</ul>';
    ?>
```

Comment: echo `$property['property'];`

Comment: @splash58, нет все таже ошибка...

Comment: да ладно?! выведите ваш массив при помощи var_export

Comment: @splash58, вывел

Comment: @splash58, извините, не так понял. отредактировал ответ

Comment: У вас ужасная путаница с именами :( , а так, конечно же, все работает - https://eval.in/942574